# Firebase - retrieving data as a LatLng object from a dataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have the following db structure:

[image]

I want to retrieve the `latitude` and `longitude` into a `LatLng` object

What i have tried so far:

```
private fun loadMarkersFromDB(){
    val query = database.getReference("spots/").orderByChild("place/latLng/")
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                var position: LatLng
                for(spotLatLng:DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                    position = spotLatLng.child("place/latLng/").value as LatLng
                    Log.d(TAG, "Database positions: $position")
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    } )
}
```

but it's not working and i get error:

> java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

Comment: You can't just cast snapshot data into whatever you want.  You will have to write code to extract the individual values and create a new object from them.

Comment: @DougStevenson ah ok thanks, i thought that since i was able to save my data as a Java object with `.setValue(myObject)` i thought i could retrieve data as an object. Thanks

Comment: The automatic serialization doesn't work with casting as you're trying to do here. If you have a JavaBean type object to read, you can try [getValue(Class)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) with it, but it will only work if the given class follows all the conventions of JavaBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug pointed out, you can't take cast snapshot data into wherever you want.

So instead, i grab the `latitude` and `longitude` individually like so:

```
private fun loadMarkersFromDB(){
    val query = database.getReference("spots/").orderByChild("place/latLng")
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                var lat: Double
                var lng: Double
                var position: LatLng
                for(spotLatLng:DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                    lat = spotLatLng.child("place/latLng/latitude/").value.toString().toDouble()
                    lng = spotLatLng.child("place/latLng/longitude/").value.toString().toDouble()
                    position = LatLng(lat, lng)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Lat: ${position.latitude} Lng: ${position.longitude}")
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    } )
}
```

If there's a better way, please let me know